# Swift generics: return type based on parameter type

Tags: swift, generics

Say I have a collection of objects inheriting from a common superclass (this is preferable to protocols in this case):

```
class ObjectSuperClass {
    type: ObjectType
}
class ObjectClass1: ObjectSuperClass {
    type = .Type1
}
class ObjectClass2: ObjectSuperClass {
    type = .Type2
}
```

I'm looking to create a generic search function like this:

```
func objectsOfType<T: ObjectSuperClass>(T.class, otherFilter: Any?) -> [T]
```

Which could be used to search for a given sub-type, returning a more specific array of results:

```
let result = objectsOfType(ObjectClass2.class, otherFilter: nil) -> [ObjectClass2]
(pseudo-swift)
```

---

I feel like this is somewhere generics could help, but cannot see where constraints should be placed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well remarkably this works...

```
func filterType<T>(list: [AnyObject]) -> [T]
{
    return list.filter{ $0 is T }.map{ $0 as! T }
}
```

...provided you assign the result to something that has been explicitly typed, as in the following example:

```
class ObjectSuperClass: CustomStringConvertible
{
    let myType: String
    init(aString: String)
    {
        myType = aString
    }
    var description: String { return myType }
}

class ObjectClass1: ObjectSuperClass
{
    init()
    {
        super.init(aString: "<t 1>")
    }
}

class ObjectClass2: ObjectSuperClass
{
    init()
    {
        super.init(aString: "<t 2>")
    }
}

let unfilteredList: [AnyObject] = [ ObjectClass1(), ObjectClass2(), ObjectSuperClass(aString: "<Who knows>")]

let filteredList1: [ObjectClass1] = filterType(list: unfilteredList)
print("\(filteredList1)") // <t 1>

let filteredList2: [ObjectClass2] = filterType(list: unfilteredList)
print("\(filteredList2)") // <t 2>

let filteredList3: [ObjectSuperClass] = filterType(list: unfilteredList)
print("\(filteredList3)") // [<t 1>, <t 2>, <Who knows>]
```

T is inferred in each case from the requested return type. The function itself filters the original array based on whether the elements are of the required type and then force casts the filtered results to the correct type.

---

If you want an "extra filter" you don't need to explicitly type the results as long as T can be inferred from your extra filter function.

```
func extraFilterType<T>(list: [AnyObject], extraFilter: T -> Bool) -> [T]
{
    return list.filter{ $0 is T }.map{ $0 as! T }.filter(extraFilter)
}

let filteredList = extraFilterType(unfilteredList){
    (element : ObjectClass2) -> Bool in
    !element.description.isEmpty
}

print("\(filteredList)") // <t 2>
```

---

**EDIT**

A slicker version of the `filterType` function would use `flatMap()`

```
func filterType<T>(list: [Any]) -> [T]
{
    return list.flatMap{ $0 as? T }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Flatmap is deprecated for optionals, since Swift 4.something, use `compactMap`

```
func filterType<T>(list: [Any]) -> [T]
{
    return list.compactMap{ $0 as? T }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, +1.Out of curiosity, could you make use of `.dynamicType` property to even sort out objects of the superclass only? E.g., `filteredList3` in your example above to yield only `[<Who knows>]`? (E.g. `return list.filter{ $0.dynamicType == T.self }.map{ $0 as! T }` doesn't work, but something along those lines?)

Comment: @dfri possibly. I haven't checked. It's not something I would normally worry about because, if I can't treat objects of a subclass as if they were objects of the base class, I take that as a code smell indicating that my class design is wrong.

Comment: @dfri Actually it works. You just have to declare the parameter for the first filter closure explicitly as an `AnyObject` i.e. `return list.filter{ (anObj: AnyObject) -> Bool in anObj.dynamicType == T.self }.map{ $0 as! T }`

Comment: I thought I might add that _if_ we want to make use of the alternative version discussed here (for "perfect type matching"), we're probably better off using `Any` instead of `AnyObject`. For the latter, non-class types (such as `Int`) will be represented as obj-c classes (e.g. for `Int`: `__NSCFNumber.Type`), and will not be found when comparing `.dynamicType` to the filter type `T` we send (e.g., if we send `Int`), whereas for `Any`, e.g. `Int` instances will be stored just as `Int` type in the `[Any]` array. This is however not an issue when doing the "less exact type check" `$0 is T`.

Comment: @dfri Just revisited the question because somebody upvoted it. You are right about `Any`. Also, we can use `flatMap` to remove the need for an explicit filter.

Answer (score 5):

This is the closest approximation I can come up with:

```
func objectsOfType<T: ObjectSuperClass>(type type: T.Type) -> [T] {
    // Just returns an array of all objects of given type
}

func objectsOfType<T: ObjectSuperClass>(type type: T.Type, predicate: T -> Bool) -> [T] {
    // Uses predicate to filter out objects of given type
}
```

Usage:

```
let bar = objectsOfType(type: ObjectClass1.self)

let baz = objectsOfType(type: ObjectClass2.self) {
    // Something that returns Bool and uses $0
}
```

Technically, you can also go without `type` argument in the above, but then you will need to have explicitly typed receivers (`bar` and `baz` in the above example) so that Swift can correctly infer the types for you and use the right version of the generic function.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the function like this:

```
func objectsOfType<T: ObjectSuperClass>(objects: [ObjectSuperClass], subclass: T.Type, otherFilter: (T->Bool)?) -> [T] {
    if let otherFilter = otherFilter {
        return objects.filter{$0 is T && otherFilter($0 as! T)}.map{$0 as! T}
    } else {
        return objects.filter{$0 is T}.map{$0 as! T}
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
objectsOfType(arrayOfObjects, subclass: ObjectClass1.self, otherFilter: nil)
```

Note that I'm not a fan of forced casting, however in this scenario it should not cause problems.

Or, the more verbose version of the function, with one less forced cast:

```
func objectsOfType<T: ObjectSuperClass>(objects: [ObjectSuperClass], subclass: T.Type, otherFilter: (T->Bool)?) -> [T] {
    return objects.filter({object in
        if let object = object as? T {
            if let otherFilter = otherFilter {
                return otherFilter(object)
            } else {
                return true
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }).map({object in
        return object as! T
    })
}
```